# How do I have multiple UITableViewControllers on the screen at once? My table just shows up blank

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

My goal is to eventually add multiple UITableViews to the screen at once and allow the user to scroll horizontally between them like columns. Right now to show my tableviewcontroller I set my custom controller to the root controller:

```
[[self window] setRootViewController: myCustomController];
```

This works fine for showing one table on the screen. However when I try changing this to:

```
[self.window addSubview: myCustomController.view];
```

Then I can see the background of my table but it doesn't load any cells into it. Likewise if I do:

```
[self.window addSubview: myCustomController.tableView];
```

then it just loads a blank table again like so:

[image]

I also tried changing the header of my custom controller to extend just UITableView instead of UITableViewController however the exact same thing happens when I try inserting the view, it's just a blank table.

I tried putting NSLogs in some of my methods and it seems like without directly inserting the controller these methods don't seem to run:

heightForRowAtIndexPath
cellForRowAtIndexPath
numberOfRowsInSection

All I want to do is figure out how I can insert multiple different instances of my custom UITableViewController on the screen so that I can use either of these:

https://github.com/alekseyn/EasyTableView
https://github.com/TheVole/HorizontalTable

To put them all side by side and display information from different data stores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not setting the `delegate` and `datasource` for the table view.

You could do this in code:

```
//assuming outlet named tableView
self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
```

Also, you will need to modify your corresponding `.h` file:

```
@interface something : somethingElse <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
....
```

If you are creating your table view through IB, make the same change to the .h file, but instead right-click drag from your table view to the little orange circle at the bottom of the 'scene'. You'll need to do this twice; once for the `dataSource` and again for the `delegate`.

Comment: This worked! Although I extended UITableView and wrote self.delegate = self and the same for dataSource.The only problem now is that my table doesnt redraw until I make a tap on the screen, and until then the space where the table would be is just white. Any ideas?

Comment: @user309641 Try calling `[self.tableView reloadData]` within your `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: I don't have a viewDidLoad anymore because now my table isn't a controller, my table has a layoutSubviews though, which is being called at the right times but the problem persists.

Comment: problem was I wasn't doing [super viewDidLoad], works great now!

Answer (score 0):

Well you have to set your table view datasource and delegates before you can load any data in it.

self.yourtableview.delegate = self;
self.yourtableview.datasouce = self;

if you don't do this your tableview wont be able to know where its instance methods are implemented in your code and won't be able to send them a call.

Now about your redraw problem until you don't tap on screen. Try calling 
[self.yourtableview reloadData] 
where you have set yourtableview's datasource and delegate. Also, if you change your contents of tableview to make them appear on your view. You will have to send a call to your reloadData instance method again.